# Retrieve item ID after adding to SharePoint list using PNPJs

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, pnp, react

I'm building a SharePoint SPFx react app. In a nutshell, the user fills out a form that I created. When the user hits submit, using PNPJs: https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/sp/items/ I'm adding the item to a list called `Request`.

From there I  send an email that contains the URL link to that item they created. Right now, my code adds the item to the list and I'm able to send an email with no problem. However, I want to get the ID of the item that was just added to the list, so that I can add it to the email.

Here is a striped down snippet of my function that adds items to the Request list.

```
async submitNewRequest():Promise<any> {

    let preprocessedData;

    try {       

        // add an item to the list
        pnp.sp.web.lists.getByTitle("Requests").items.add({
            Title: this.state.Title,
            Requestor_x0020_Email: this.state.getEmail,
            Created: this.state.startDate,

        }).then((iar) => {
            console.log(iar);
            //Is this where I would get the ID 
        }); 
            
        const emailProps: EmailProperties = {
            To: [this.state.getEmail],
            Subject: "Your court requisition has been submitted.",
            Body: this.initalMessage
        };
        
    } catch(error) {

    }

    return preprocessedData;            


}
```

I believe what I have to do is in the `.then((iar) => {` when item is successfully added to the list, to get a response back with that item ID. But I'm not sure how. In my `const emailProps: EmailProperties` is where I'm sending the email, which again works.

Typically I can do something like this `await sp.web.lists.getByTitle("Request").items.getById(1).get();` and in the console I will get back something like this:

```
0:
Title: "My title here"
Description: "Description Here"
ID: 24
```

Here is on submit function:

```
async _onNewRequest(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    await this.submitNewRequest();
    this.displayPop();
}
```

And lastly my email function:

```
get initalMessage() {
    return `<p>This is my email template that I stripped down.</p>
    
    &nbsp;
    <p>
    <a href="https://mywebsite.sharepoint.com/sites/Requests/SitePages/Home.aspx#/MyRequests/'+ NEED_ID_HERE +'" target="_blank">
        Click Here
    </a>
</p>`;
```

Comment: crossposted in [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67795738/retrieve-id-after-pushing-to-sharepoint-list-using-react-pnpjs)

Answer (score 0):

Based on their [GitHub](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-JS-Core/wiki/Basic--Operations) Page

as per your code you can use "iar.item" to get new list item details

```
pnp.sp.web.lists.getByTitle("Tasks").items.add({
    Title: "My Item Title"
}).then(r => {
    
    // this result will have two properties "data" and "item"
    // data is what was returned from SharePoint after the add operation
    // and item is an object of type item representing the REST query to that item
    // so you can immediately chain off that

    console.log(r);

    // this will add an attachment to the item we just created
    r.item.attachmentFiles.add("file.txt", "Here is some file content.");

});
```